# Automatically add a certain class, whenever <Form> code contains a certain value?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to add a special class to each form that contains the word `special` as part of its action URL.

But I have many forms, and I can't think of an automated way to do this.

The only way I came up with was to create the following code, but I will have to create such code for each and every form, using a different index number:

```
<?php
$case1 = "special"; 
$case2 = "none"; 

if($case1 == "none") { 
  $class1 = ""; // don't add any class
}
else {
  $class1 = "effect"; // add `effect` class
}

if($case2 == "none") { 
  $class2 = ""; // same goes here
}
else {
  $class2 = "effect"; // and here
}
?>
```

HTML:

```
   <form action="/go/<?= $case1 ?>" method="POST" target="_blank">
   <input type="submit" class="<?= $class1 ?> general-class" value="submit">
   </form>
   <form action="/go/<?= $case2 ?>" method="POST" target="_blank">
   <input type="submit" class="<?= $class2 ?> general-class" value="submit">
   </form>
```

OUTPUT:

```
   <form action="/go/special" method="POST" target="_blank">
   <input type="submit" class="effect general-class" value="submit">
   </form>
   <form action="/go/none" method="POST" target="_blank">
   <input type="submit" class="general-class" value="submit">
   </form>
```

Is there any automated way to do this?

Basically I have two types of forms, one should be opened using a `jquery` plugin (henace the special class), and the other should open in a normal way.

My way to differentiate between them is to insert the `$case[i]` variable into the action url, as this is something that I have to do either way.

Perhaps there's a complete different way to achieve this, I don't know.

EDIT:

Real Form is generated mostly manually, with this code:

```
    <form action="/go/<?= $item ?>/<?php echo $case1 ; ?>" method="POST" target="_blank">
      <input name="a" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $a; ?>"/>
      <input name="b" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $b; ?>"/>
      <input name="c" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $c; ?>"/>
      <input name="d" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $d; ?>"/>
      <input type="submit" class="<?= $class1 ?> general-class" value="Click Me"></form>
```

(all variables are being given values at the start of the PHP block you see above)

Comment: You could use jQuery selectors like this: $('form[action*="special"]'); to find forms that include the word special in the action attribute. Then you could use the addClass('some-css-class') method to add some-css-class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two ways - PHP and jQuery.  Based on your code, we don't have enough info to know if we can use the PHP way or not, so here's the jQuery way:

```
// wait until the document is ready
jQuery(function($) {
    // find all forms that have "special" in the action
    $('form[action*="special"]').each(
        function() {
            // within the form, find the submit button, and add the "effect" class
            $(this).find('input[type="submit"]').addClass('effect');
        }
    );
});
```

And, the shorter / less verbose way:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    // find all forms that have "special" in the action, find their input, and add the class
    $('form[action*="special"] input[type="submit"]').addClass('effect');
});
```

## The PHP Way

So, to do this in PHP, I would recommend writing a simple function, then calling it.

```
function get_class( $slug ) {
    $class_map = array(
        'special' => 'effect',
        'none'    => '',
        // .. you could add others here if appropriate

    return ( isset( $class_map[ $slug ] ) ) ? $class_map[ $slug ] : '';
);
```

Then you could use it in your php like so:

```
<form action="/go/<?= $item ?>/<?php echo $case1 ; ?>" method="POST" target="_blank">
  <input name="a" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $a; ?>"/>
  <input name="b" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $b; ?>"/>
  <input name="c" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $c; ?>"/>
  <input name="d" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $d; ?>"/>
  <input type="submit" class="<?= get_class( $case1 ); ?> general-class" value="Click Me"></form>
```

While that may not seem like a big value, if you started applying those *concepts* to your code, you would quickly see the value start adding up.

Comment: For some reason this doesn't work :/ does it take into account the fact that `special` may be just a part of the action string, and not the whole of it?

Comment: Or perhaps I have to insert some `$(document).ready(function` somewhere? if so, I'm not sure how..

Comment: @rockyraw - the code I provided includes a document ready.  This *may not* work if it's being fired *after* your other javascript code is binding to those inputs.

Comment: my bad. I was using `view-source` to check if it works, didn't realize that it would only show me the code before script actually runs. Thanks. however, since I prefer that visitors won't see this trick in the source code, can you elaborate also about the PHP solution?  what info do you need? I have PHP 5 on my server.

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error in the last two lines. Also, I'm not sure I understand the code, how does it know to look inside the `action` field for the value?

Comment: What's the syntax error exactly? ("Syntax error in the last two lines" is hard to work with!).  Also, it knows based on the `$case1` variable, which is "passed in" to the `get_class()` function

Comment: I can't tell what' the error, it's Dreamweaver saying it is on the 8th line, and that's it.. I guess there's some `(` or `;` that shouldn't be there?

Comment: What are the contents of line 7 and 8 (and maybe 9)? There's NO way to guess at this - I can't see what you see!

Comment: line 8 is the one that says `return ( isset( $class_map[ $slug ] ) ) ? $class_map[ $slug ] : '';`

Comment: the array was not being closed in the code with `);` but now I'm getting fatal error, please see [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34827041/cannot-redeclare-get-class-error/34827173)