# Cannot redeclare get_class() error

Tags: php

I'm trying to apply the class `effect` into `input type="submit"` whenever its parent form action contains the string `special`.

I'm using the following code, but Dreamweaver tells me there are syntax error in lines 15,16,22:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

$case1 = "special"; 
$item = "aaa"; 
$item = "something"; 

function get_class( $slug ) {
    $class_map = array(
        'special' => 'effect',
        'none'    => '',
        // .. you could add others here if appropriate

    return ( isset( $class_map[ $slug ] ) ) ? $class_map[ $slug ] : ''; //line 15
);  // line 16
?>
<HTML>
<body>
<form action="/go/<?= $item ?>/<?php echo $case1 ; ?>" method="POST" target="_blank">
<input name="a" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $a; ?>"/>
<input type="submit" class="<?= get_class( $case1 ); ?> general-class" value="Click Me"></form> // line 22
</body>
</HTML>
```

The output is empty, and no errors are being displayed when I try running the file.

What's wrong?

**Edit 2 - Updated code:**

Now getting fatal error on line 16:

`Fatal error: Cannot redeclare get_class() on line 16`

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

$case1 = "special"; 
$item = "aaa"; 
$item = "something"; 

function get_class( $slug ) {
    $class_map = array(
        'special' => 'effect',
        'none'    => '',
        // .. you could add others here if appropriate
);
    return ( isset( $class_map[ $slug ] ) ) ? $class_map[ $slug ] : '';
} // line 16
?>
<HTML>
<body>
<form action="/go/<?= $item ?>/<?php echo $case1 ; ?>" method="POST" target="_blank">
<input name="a" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $a; ?>"/>
<input type="submit" class="<?php get_class( $case1 ); ?> general-class" value="Click Me"></form>
</body>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Where are you closing your array?

Comment: Line 14 should have a closing bracket for the array above. The `return` statement cannot occur _inside_ the array, that's why you get an error on line 15.

Comment: your array is broken

Comment: ok, but even when array is closed, I'm still getting syntax errors inside that HTML block.

Comment: @arkascha I updated the code to close the array before `return`, still getting error on the last line though.

Comment: Unbelievable. You _are_ aware that you now do not close that function?

Comment: Is Dreamweaver such a bad programming editor that it is not even able to point out such basic issues? Switch to a usable development environment then.

Comment: ok, I closed it, now getting fatal error when running. what do you recommeand btw? I'm working with it because it also designs the page.

Answer (score 0):

I have very little coding in PHP, and have forgotten most of it's syntaxes. However, from basic understanding, it seems that If that is your entire code base, then you are missing either of "}" (closing brace for function get_class) or you have misplaced your closing $class_ map array in the following code :

```
function get_class( $slug ) {
    $class_map = array(
        'special' => 'effect',
        'none'    => '',
        // .. you could add others here if appropriate

        return ( isset( $class_map[ $slug ] ) ) ? $class_map[ $slug ] : '';    //line 15
      );  // line 16
```

Your code should be either of the following two:

```
function get_class( $slug ) {
    $class_map = array(
        'special' => 'effect',
        'none'    => ''
    );

    return ( isset( $class_map[ $slug ] ) ) ? $class_map[ $slug ] : '';
}
```

OR

```
function get_class( $slug ) {
    $class_map = array(
        'special' => 'effect',
        'none'    => '',
        return ( isset( $class_map[ $slug ] ) ) ? $class_map[ $slug ] : '';
    );
}
```

The last one don't seem appropriate/feasible to me though.

Comment: **AFAIK** you cannot use `return` in an array.